# why MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED is not working on huawei?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, huawei-mobile-services

I have added a broadcast receiver in and android application with MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED as an intent filter.
it seems to be working fine on Nokia and Samsung devices however testing it on Huawei (P20/P30 Pro) device is not working.

Has anyone face this problem before?

I have added broadcast receiver in the manifest and added toast message onReceive function.
I installed the app using adb install on Nokia and Samsung device.
I incremented the versionCode in gradle.
I ran the app using adb install.
and the toast shows up as expected.
but the same scenarios wont work on Huawei

here's the link for the code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11F40Ik2CkrM4zJELZFW0QuR_StzzVdCE/view?usp=sharing